# Django Page not found(404) error (Library not found)

Tags: python, django

This is my music\urls.py code:-

```
     #/music/
url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index'),

#/music/712/
url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

And this is my views.py code:-

```
def index(request):
return HttpResponse("This will be a list of all the albums")

def detail(request, album_id):
return HttpResponse("Details for album id: " + str(album_id))
```

Now why am I getting a Page not found(404) error whenever I try to open this link 127.0.0.1:8000/music/2/ in browser

ERROR MESSAGE:-

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2/
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^music ^/$ [name='index']
^music ^(?P[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
The current URL, music/2/, didn't match any of these.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osUAr.png)

Comment: Place code inside of question please.  See [ask].

Comment: ... because `music` is not part of your urls config.

Comment: Don't post screenshots, copy and past the the actual code. Please include the error message - the 404 debug page will show which patterns were tried which will help solve the problem. You need to show how you are including `music.urls` as well.

Comment: This is the error message:-Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2/

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^music ^/$ [name='index']
^music ^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
The current URL, music/2/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @Alasdair please help sir!

Comment: As I said before - you need to show how you are including `music.urls` as well.

Comment: @Alasdair sorry iam new to django, i dont know much about it.    is this what you are asking:-    from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

Comment: @Alasdair or maybe this:-    
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music', include('music.urls'))
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url patterns are missing the slash between `music` and `<album_id>` - currently, they would match `/music2/` instead of `/music/2/`.

Add the missing slash to the url pattern that includes the music urls:

```
url('^music/', include('music.urls')),
```

Then remove the slash from your index pattern to avoid a double slash.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```